# Git short sha work on Linux, not on Windows

Tags: github, github-actions

I use Github actions to build app.

I release my app with short sha.
I do

```
- name: Set SHORT Sha
        run: echo "SHORT_SHA=$(git rev-parse --short ${{ github.sha }})" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

I can echo the short sha on MacOS and Linux but on Windows.

I dont inderstand why

Comment: Bash syntax vs cmd vs powershell?

Comment: Bashism `$(do anything)` doesn't work in any Win-shell, never

Comment: You can add the `shell: bash` configuration to the step to guaranty bash will always be used, independently of the runner OS.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Is `bash` available on Windows at Github Actions?

Comment: [Yes it is](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell). When specifying a bash shell on Windows, the bash shell included with Git for Windows is used.

Answer (score 0):

`shell: bash` does the job
Thanks to @GuiFalourd